# Android How to create Our own folder under images directory?

Tags: android

We have an app which downloads images and store them on the device. The image is stored, but we are not able to see our app folder when we open the gallery. Here is the code we use to create directory:

```
public File getDataFolder(Context context) {
    File dataDir = null;
    if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        dataDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + File.separator + "MYAPPNAME");

        if(!dataDir.isDirectory()) {
            dataDir.mkdirs();
        }
    }
    if(!dataDir.isDirectory()) {
        dataDir = context.getFilesDir();
    }

    return dataDir;
}
```

Also we have noticed, Folder is visible in Jelly bean but not in KitKat+ devices. Why it's not visible in gallery? (files are .jpg format)

Comment: But they are visible in the Gallery app after rebooting your device!?

Comment: `Folder is visible`. You mean in the Gallery? Try a file explorer too.

Comment: Your post and question are confusing as you first say that the image is stored.

Comment: @greenapps After rebooting it appeared, How? without reboot it wont be visible? Folder is visible in Jelly bean , yeah inside galley we are able to see it. What we meant by "image is stored" is because Image after downloading we are able to pass it to an intent, which means image is getting downloaded and saved, but its not visible inside gallery (without restart)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using getExternalFilesDirs()?

> Use getExternalFilesDirs() (note the plural). If that returns more than one entry, the second and subsequent ones are on removable media. Those directories you can read and write to without any permissions on Android 4.4.

From this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/26006099/5837758.

### EDIT

If the folder appears after rebooting, then you need to add your image to the gallery. From the Taking Photos Simply tutorial (http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html):

```
private void galleryAddPic() {
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}
```

Comment: I also recommend checking the Taking Photos Simply tutorial, it has a section about adding photos to gallery [http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html)

Answer (score 1):

You have to invoke the media scanner on your new file upon that file being visible in the Gallery without reboot. Call the media scaner after ever file saved.

Only a few lines of code will do. Code has been published very often on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to Android Kitkat, third-party apps had access to external storage, but from Kitkat, this permission is revoked. Now you can store data in the internal memory of the device only.

Comment: But we can see folders like Whatsapp Images, OGQ wallpapers, Deviantart etc.. how they are creating it?

Comment: As the statement is not true. All apps can do with external storage what they want. But for removable storage access is restricted. For security reasons which do not apply for external storage.